# Deux mots différents pour "marsh" et "swamp"

Tags: traduction, synonymes

Je cherche à traduire une liste de différents types de terrains qui inclut à la fois "marsh" et "swamp". Si je comprend bien, la différence se situe dans le fait que le "swamp" est recouvert par des arbres, alors que ce n'est pas le cas du "marsh".

D'après wordreference.com, ces deux mots sont traduits par "marais" ou "marécage", mais pour autant que je le sache il n'y a pas en français de différence entre un marais et un marécage.

Comment traduire ces deux mots tout en marquant leur différence ?

Comment: The categories may not align exactly. Actually, I think *marais* can often be more watery than either English word, more like a "wetland", while *marécage* is more like swamp/marsh. But I don't really know.

Comment: @LukeSawczak en anglais "wetland" est le terme générique alors que "marsh" et "swamp" sont des sous-catégories.

Answer (score 4):

An unspoken rule seems to be using "*marais*" for "swamp" and "*marécage*" for "marsh". All the examples I found for MTG cards follow this pattern.

It's definitely not the first time translators came across this issue, and what I would do is look at how others solved it. Card games are great for that because oftentimes names have to be very consistent.

For example the keyword "cat" was translated to "*chat*", when the game had few "cat" cards and it didn't matter that much. However as a creature type, "*félin*" would be more fitting since it includes lions, tigers, etc. But once they've chosen a word they have to stick to it. It's likely that's what they did for marsh/swamp.

Answer (score 3):

Dans certain contextes les deux termes peuvent signifier la même chose (ou être confondus, comme *pingouin* et *manchot*), mais pas toujours.

Selon *Linguee*, [les traductions pour *swamp* sont *marais* et *marécage*](https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/marsh.html), alors que [celles pour *marsh* sont *marécage* et *étang*](https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/swamp.html).

Une autre technique assez utile (particulairement pour des termes techniques) est de les trouver en wikipedia et regarder la page correspondante en langue ciblée. Pour *swamp* et *marsh* ça produit [*Marécage*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mar%C3%A9cage) et [*Marais*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marais).